# How to determine sort field when left join in mysql symfony?

Tags: mysql, symfony

I'm working symfony and use rest API. I get a list users and their transactions include columns : ID, email, first name, last name, method, amount. So my query is:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, ud.first_name, ud.last_name, t.method, t.amount
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON u.id = t.user_id
```

And in symfony I use doctrine query builder, ORM:

```
$qb = $this->userRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb->select('u.id, u.email, ud.firstName, ud.lastName, t.method, t.amount')
   ->leftJoin('u.userDetail', 'ud')
   ->leftJoin('u.transactions','t');
```

I would like to sort any column of list. So my idea is pass query string in url, like : `/users-list?sortField=email&sortDirection=DESC`
And I will process :

```
if(isset($request->query->get('sortField')) && isset($request->query->get('sortDirection'))){
   $sortField = $request->query->get('sortField');
   $sortDirection = $request->query->get('sortDirection'));
   $qb->orderBy('u.' . $sortField, $sortDirection);
}
```

But if sortField is 'firstName', 'lastName' then alias must be `'ud.' . $sortField` , if sortField is 'method', 'amount' then alias must be `'t.' . $sortField`.
How can I handle all case ? My idea is use if else or switch case, but suppose left join many table or many column, it's quite verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The example you've provided is prone to sql injection attacks. Since users directly manipulate the query via the query parameter.

I suggest you go for the switch case. It is indeed more verbose but safer and more readable.

You could improve/shorten your code by using

`if($sortField = $request->get('sortField'){  switch(sortField) { ...`